# What is the best way to create REST for nosql with Django and Titan?

Tags: python, django, rest, titan, nosql

Hello all and have a nice day! I wonder, how can i create REST with django-rest-framework and my nosql objects orm. For example i have bulbflow, which connects to my graph database  Titan. Bulbflow allows you to make usual queries in ORM style like this:

```
MyNosqlobject.objects.all()
```

What i want is to be able to access my object via REST interface from javascript, but MyNosqlobject is not usual django model. It is actually a proxy for graph vertice.

Answer (score 4):

I had to do something similar, in my case creating an API for a dynamoDB table, but I think this solution would apply to any NoSQL object, assuming it is serializable. For example, if you have a python Dict object.

In short, a lot of the cool functionality in Django Rest Framework requires Django Models, but you can still do a lot without them.

The following is an example for creating a 'list' of all objects. I am hard coding an array to make the case, but hopefully this makes it clear

```
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework import serializers

class NoSQLSerializer(serializers.BaseSerializer):
   def to_representation(self, obj):
      # If you don't have a json serializable object
      # you can do the transformations here
      return obj

class NoSQLViewSet(generics.ListAPIView):

   serializer_class = NoSQLSerializer

   def get_queryset(self):
     if self.request.user.is_anonymous():
        return None

     # This is just an example, In a real NoSQL database
     # you can just return the python representation of the 
     # object
     obj_list = [
       { 'name':'foo', 'type':1 },
       { 'name':'bar', 'type':2 },
       { 'name':'foobar', 'type':1 },
     ]

     return obj_list
```

I have not been able to figure out how to use (or if I can use) a Router, so I had to add to the url list as:

```
from .api_views import NoSQLViewSet

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^api/v1/yourObjName/', NoSQLViewSet.as_view(), name='api-nosql'),
)
```

but after that, all works very well, including the HTML views.

I don't know anything about Titan, but it may be that all you need to do in your case is define the get_queryset in my example as

```
class NoSQLViewSet(generics.ListAPIView):

   serializer_class = TitanSerializer

   def get_queryset(self):
       return MyNosqlobject.objects.all()
```

and then just focus on getting a TitanSerializer to work.

Hope this helps.